# error in mysql connection "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: asp.net, mysql, connection-string

I have problem while connecting to mysql database using "ADO.NET Driver for MySQL (Connector/NET)"

I got this exception `The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

**Edit:**

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=pgs_db;Uid=root;Pwd=;"); 
MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(); 
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Connection = con;
com.CommandText = "getStudent";
con.Open();

MySqlDataReader dr =com.ExecuteReader(); 
GridView1.DataSource = dr; 
GridView1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Post the code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Posting the full exception stack trace might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry i was using a worng connectionstring

this is a right one :

```
"server=localhost; user id=user; password=password; database=mydatabase; pooling=false;"
```

thnx Oded

Comment: Now i getting "Resource not found" when i tried with connectionstring. My code got worse.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, I am guessing you are trying to access a configuration key that does not exist in your application config file.

**Edit:**
After seeing the code sample, the problem is probably *not* with connecting to the DB.

I would say that in your `GridView`, you are binding to a field that is not returned by the DB query.

Comment: MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=pgs_db;Uid=root;Pwd=;");
        
        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = "getStudent";
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr =com.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();

Comment: i'm not using a configuration file , i have the connection string as plain text as above

Comment: Changed answer following comment. @mahmoud - when posting code examples, please add them to the question.